# javax.swing.JComboBox cannot be cast to javax.swing.ComboBoxModel

Tags: java, pointers, combobox, null, jcombobox

i use ComboBox in java.when i sent item of ComboBox to another class.

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:   javax.swing.JComboBox cannot be cast to javax.swing.ComboBoxModel
    at ekspeditorv3.Odenish.jComboBox1ActionPerformed(Odenish.java:144)
    at ekspeditorv3.Odenish.access$300(Odenish.java:16)
    at ekspeditorv3.Odenish$4.actionPerformed(Odenish.java:74)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(JComboBox.java:1258)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(JComboBox.java:1331)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.intervalRemoved(JComboBox.java:1351)`

This is my code :

```
private void jComboBox1ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
   Qosulma.BorcuGoster(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString(), BorcLabel);
 }
```

It is my qosulma class :

```
static void BorcuGoster(String toString, JLabel jLabel3) {
        try {
            Statement statYoxla = con.createStatement();
            String Query2 = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE  CUSTOMERNAME='" + toString + "'";
            ResultSet rsYoxla = statYoxla.executeQuery(Query2);
            double say = 0;
            while (rsYoxla.next()) {
                say = say + rsYoxla.getDouble(6);
            }
            jLabel3.setText(String.valueOf(say));
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Qosulma.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception (caused by incompatible type casting) occurs at this method: `jComboBox1ActionPerformed`. If it's a method you wrote, check what you do there. If it's a method from a library which you didn't write, read its documentation and make sure you use it as you're supposed to.